# Why does VIM create a X~ file for every X?

Tags: text-editor, vim

What is the purpose of the X~ files? And if its unnecessary, is there a way to prevent Vim from creating one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

its a backup file, every time you save while modifying something it will create one.  There's an option to turn it off.

[See here from the vim faq](http://vimdoc.sf.net/cgi-bin/vimfaq2html3.pl#7.1)

Answer (score 7):

This is a backup file that contains a copy of the previous revision of the file.

You can change this behavior by adding a line to the end of your .vimrc file:

```
set nobackup
```

Answer (score 6):

What I personally do is that I create a folder `$HOME/.vim/backupfiles` that will contain all my backup files, instead of leaving them all scattered around.

My `.vimrc` contains the following:

```
set backupdir=~/.vim/backupfiles,~/tmp,.
```

This way you have the protection of backup files but avoid the littering of your folders with `*~` files.

Comment: This could cause name-clashes if you have files with the same name. I don't know if vim resolves this, or even if this is likely, but it could happen.

Comment: @sykora, yes it does happen, if you edit two files with the same name, the older backup will be rewritten, but I've never had an issue with that, and personally I think it's a good trade off.

Answer (score 3):

Turn it off using

```
:se nobackup
```

You can also tell it to put the backup file in a different location by using:

```
:se directory=c:\temp
```

Answer (score 3):

Vim is creating backup files automatically. To turn it off you have to add the following line to your .vimrc config file:

> set nobackup

Answer (score 2):

They are backup files. Maybe `:set nowritebackup` will turn off this feature.